# Decorating class method at runtime

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator

I want to decorate a class method, but at runtime (by that I mean that the decorator does not need to be specified before the method with the @ notation)

See this example of a standard method decorator:

```
def method_decorator(func):
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorator:', args, kwargs)
        return func(self,*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

class Standard():
    @ method_decorator
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated: ', args, kwargs)

s = Standard()
s.decorated(1,2)
```

Result:

```
decorator: (1, 2) {}
decorated:  (1, 2) {}
```

So I tried different ways to do it at runtime:

```
class RunTime():
    def set_decorator_1(self, decorator):
        self.decorated = decorator(self.decorated)
    def set_decorator_2(self, decorator):
        RunTime.decorated = decorator(RunTime.decorated)
    def set_decorator_3(self, decorator):
        self.decorated = decorator(RunTime.decorated)
    def set_decorator_4(self, decorator):
        setattr(self, 'decorated', decorator(RunTime.decorated))
    def set_decorator_5(self, decorator):
        setattr(self, 'decorated', decorator(self.decorated))
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated: ', args, kwargs)

r = RunTime()
r.set_decorator_*(method_decorator)
r.decorated(1,2)
```

And here are the outputs:

1. The decorator is not properly decorated:

```
decorator: (2,) {}
decorated:  (1, 2) {}
```

2. Works as expected, but when set_decorator is called, all RunTime instances are also decorated, which I want to avoid, because I only want to decorate the method of a single instance.
3. Bad decoration

```
decorator: (2,) {}
decorated:  (2,) {}
```

4. same as 3
5. same as 1

I also tries another decorator, which works well (with set_decorator_1) but does not allow me to access self in it:

```
def method_decorator_runtime(func):
    def decorated( *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorator: ', args, kwargs)
        return func( *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Does anyone know a proper way of decorating a method at run time, with ability to access self in the decorator ?

Comment: "Works as expected, but when set_decorator is called, all RunTime classes are decorated ..." What does this mean? Do you mean that *all instances* are affected by decorating the method? But of course that would be the case. Are you trying to *avoid* that?

Comment: By the way, your standard method happens at runtime as well. I guess I'm entirely sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited the question to clarify those points

Comment: Is this not something you solve with an if statement and `def foo(do_decoratory_things_too=True)`?

Comment: Methods are part of the class not the instance, so it's not surprising. However when you do it, it fill affect all existing and well a future instances. If you want to access `self` in the deocrator, recall that it's the first argument in `*args`.

Comment: "because I only want to decorate a single instance." This is the fundamental issue. You don't *decorate instances*. You decorate functions. Methods are function objects that are shared by all instances in a class. One potential solution is to define your decorator, `def decorator(func, self): ...` and explicitly pass self, so `self.decorated = decorator(decorated, self)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Passing `self` won't make the instance's decorated version of the method be called.

Comment: @Sayse The decorated method might be often called, so I would prefer the if statement being executed only once and calling set_decorator, than being called many times inside the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest solution I have found for your question is to use a decorator with an argument where you can pass the instance of the object that has its method decorated.

```py
def method_decorator(self_eventually):
    def decorator(func):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            print('decorator:', repr(self_eventually), args, kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator

class RunTime():

    def set_decorator(self, decorator):
        self.decorated = decorator(self)(self.decorated)

    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated:', repr(self), args, kwargs)

r = RunTime()
r.set_decorator(method_decorator)
r.decorated(1, 2)
```